# WPF UserControl Not Displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, prism

I deleted my previous question to rephrase appropriately, since my previous post was neither helpful nor complete, imo.

For clarity: I'm using the Prism framework and abiding by a strict MVVM pattern.

**Problem**: When I load a `UserControl`, defined in some module, `ModuleA`, it does not display in the `Shell` view. However, if I load my `UserControl` within an `ItemsControl`, the elements I have defined appear, but they are all 'squished together'.

In ModuleA, I have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...
             ...>

...

<Grid>
    ... My Content Here ...
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, in my project, I have defined the `Shell` thusly:

```
<Window ...
        ...>

...

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" .../>

    <UserControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ModuleARegion"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="2" .../>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, in this scenario, everything loads, and `ModuleA` is recognized, but nothing appears on the screen.

However, if I change the `<UserControl Grid.Row="0" prism:RegionManger .../>` to `<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" prism:RegionManager .../>`, I can see the content I've laid out in my `ModuleA` `UserControl`, but the content is all 'squished together'.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you sure about the `RowHeight` being `10` pixels only? perhaps you should try something else or `Auto` or `*` instead

Comment: I am talking about the RowDefinition *

Comment: @bit Yes, I just used 10 for this example. It can be whatever you want. The point is more in the fact that nothing is displayed in the 1st (0-indexed) Row.

Comment: Try to place the `Border` in the Row indexed 0, and place the `UserControl` inside it. Then you can use the `BorderThickness` and other properties according to your need.

Comment: As @JamesLucas said this is not supported for UserControl. You would have to write your own custom region adapter by creating a class and inherit from RegionAdapter<T> T as a user control in this case. And then override Adapt method. Finally in the Bootstrapper you would have to override RegionAdapterMappings and register mapping for your custom region adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The default region adaptors in Prism don't support UserControl. You need to use ContentControl, ItemsControl or a Selector based control like a ComboBox to get out of the box support or write your own region adaptor.

Note: The region adaptor is used to add and remove controls from regions of a certain type of control when you interact with its regions.